# Is it possible to call a slot when any of the widgets in a dialog box emits a signal?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qcombobox

I am trying to create a configuration menu box for an application, and have used a QDialog box to display the options that the user can change. This box contains QComboBoxes and QLineEdits, but a lot of them (7 combo boxes and 12 line edits). There is a QPushButton in the bottom called "Apply Changes" that should get enabled only when any property in the box gets changed.

Do I have to link every signal from each widget with a slot to enable the button individually or is there a signal that the QDialog box itself emits when there is a change in its constituent widgets?

Right now I have this:

```
connect(Combo1,SIGNAL(activated(QString)),this,SLOT(fnEnable(QString)));
connect(Combo2,SIGNAL(activated(QString)),this,SLOT(fnEnable(QString)))
```

followed by 17 more lines of these connections.

```
void MyClass::fnEnable(QString)
{
ApplyButton->setEnabled(true); //It is initialised as false
}
```

I was wondering if there was a shorter way of doing this, maybe (like I mentioned before) a signal emitted by QDialog (I couldn't find one in the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdialog.html))

I know that this does not speed up the program, as only the required connection is called, but it would make any further attempts at making more ambitious dialog boxes easier.

Comment: Actually there is no such signal, but one approach is to create a list of QComboBox, and make the connections with a for, for example: `QList <*QCombobox> l; l<<combobox1<< combobox2<< ....; for (auto combo: l) {connect(combo, SIGNAL(activated(QString)), this, SLOT(fnEnable(QString))}`. The same would be done with QLineEdit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually there is no such signal, but one approach is to create a list of `QComboBox`, and make the connections with a for, for example:

```
QList <*QCombobox> l; 

l<<combobox1<< combobox2<< ....; 

for (auto combo: l) {
    connect(combo, &QComboBox::activated, this, &MyClass::fnEnable);
}
```

The same would be done with `QLineEdit`.

Comment: This works! This is a neat way of making the compiler do the grunt work. I had to change the `for` statement to `foreach(QComboBox* combo, 1)` (I forgot to mention I was using VC++), but it worked like a charm.

Comment: I do not work vc ++, but maybe you can enable "for" by adding `CONFIG+=c++14` to your .pro file

Comment: `foreach` does the exact same thing though; it's just that I have to explicitly mention the type for `combo`.

Comment: Conceptually it does the same thing, but the one created in the standard c ++ 14 is faster than the foreach :P

Comment: I genuinely did not know that :o. I need to read about this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over an initializer list of widgets boxes and leverage C++11 to do all the boring work for you:

```
MyClass::MyClass(QWidget * parent) : QWidget(parent) {
  auto const comboBoxes = {Combo1, Combo2, ... };
  for (auto combo : comboBoxes)
    connect(combo, &QComboBox::activates, this, &MyClass::fnEnable);
}
```

You can also automatically find all the combo boxes:

```
MyClass::MyClass(QWidget * parent) : QWidget(parent) {
  ui.setupUi(this); // or other setup code
  for (auto combo : findChildren<QComboBox*>(this))
    connect(combo, &QComboBox::activated, this, &MyClass::fnEnable);
}
```

Or you can automatically attach to the user property's change signal. This will work on all controls that have the user property. The user property is the property of a control that contains the primary data the control is displaying.

```
void for_layout_widgets(QLayout * layout, const std::function<void(QWidget*)> & fun, 
                        const std::function<bool(QWidget*)> & pred = +[](QWidget*){ return true; })
{
  if (!layout) return;
  for (int i = 0; i < layout->count(); ++i) {
    auto item = layout->itemAt(i);
    for_layout_widgets(item->layout(), fun, pred);
    auto widget = item->widget();
    if (widget && pred(widget)) fun(widget);
  }
}

class MyClass : public QWidget {
  Q_OBJECT
  Q_SLOT void MyClass::fnEnable(); // must take no arguments
  ...
};

MyClass::MyClass(QWidget * parent) : QWidget(parent) {
  // setup code here
  auto slot = metaObject()->method(metaObject()->indexOfMethod("fnEnable()"));
  Q_ASSERT(slot.isValid());
  for_layout_widgets(layout(), [=](QWidget * widget){
    auto mo = widget->metaObject();
    auto user = mo->userProperty();
    if (!user.isValid()) return;
    auto notify = user.notifySignal();
    if (!notify.isValid()) return;
    connect(widget, notify, this, slot);
  });
}
```

You can also keep the combo boxes in an array, by value. This minimizes the costs of indirect references and results in code that will take the least amount of memory possible and perform well:

```
class MyClass : public QWidget {
  Q_OBJECT
  QVBoxLayout m_layout{this};
  std::array<QComboBox, 14> m_comboBoxes;
  ...
};

MyClass(QWidget * parent) : QWidget(parent) {
  for (auto & combo : m_comboBoxes) {
    m_layout.addWidget(&combo);
    connect(&combo, &QComboBox::activates, this, &MyClass::fnEnable);
  }
}
```

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, how is the third method different from the first one? Are lists and arrays handled differently? Or is it faster because you aren't adding existing combo boxes to a list, rather creating an array of combo boxes on initialization?

Comment: The third method is different because you hold the combo boxes in an array by value. In the first method, you have to create a container of pointers to combo boxes. You ask me for gumballs. In the first method, I give you a stack of post-its, each one with a location in the house where a piece of gumball is hidden. In the second method, I give you a tube filled with gumballs. It's easy to see which method is more efficient to get at the gumballs, and also which method is least prone to error.